# Speeding up the process of list-appending via if else statements

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list that contains strings that are a combination of "A", "B" and "C".

For example:

```
abc_list = ["AB", "AC", "AB", "BC", "BB", ...]
```

I now want to create a new list that translates every element again to "A", "B" and "C" with a simple rule.

The rule is as follows:

If the element is "AA", "AB" or "BA", then the new string element has to become "A".
If the element is "BB", "AC” or "CA”, then the new string element has to become "B".
If the element is "CC", "CB" or "BC", then the new string element has to become "C".

So the new list becomes:

```
new_abc_list = ["A", "B", "A", "C", "B", ...]
```

I'm doing it as follow for the moment, but I got a feeling it can be done much more efficient.

```
new_abc_list = []
for element in abc_list :
    if element == "AA":
        new_abc_list .append("A")
    elif element == "AB":
        new_abc_list .append("A")
    elif element == "BA":
        new_abc_list .append("A")
    elif element == "CB":
        new_abc_list .append("C")
    elif element == "CC":
        new_abc_list .append("C")
    elif element == "BC":
        new_abc_list .append("C")
    else:
        new_abc_list .append("B")
return new_abc_list
```

What is a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Yes sorry that was a mistake. Corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a good job for a dictionary and a list comprehension:

```
mapper = {"AA": "A", "AB": "A", "BA": "A", "CB": "C", "CC": "C", "BC": "C"}

abc_list = ["AB", "AC", "AB", "BC", "BB"]

# find the value from key, default to 'B' if not found
new_abc_list = [mapper.get(x, 'B') for x in abc_list]
```

Output:

```
['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B']
```

Complexity will be O(n) as dictionary search is O(1). In contrast your original code has to test all values until it find a match for each item in the loop.

##### timings

On 500k items (`abc_list = ["AB", "AC", "AB", "BC", "BB"] * 100_000`) with 6 tests:

```
# dictionary with list comprehension
27.8 ms ± 1.94 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# dictionary with for loop and append
56.4 ms ± 12.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# loop with tests
84.8 ms ± 11.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

worst case: 500k items that are not matching any test (`abc_list = ['ZZ']*500_000`):

```
# dictionary with list comprehension
35.1 ms ± 4.08 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# dictionary with for loop and append
48.2 ms ± 2.62 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# loop with tests
124 ms ± 20.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: I mean, the original code is also O(N).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga not in terms of matching the values, its need to test all if/elif until the match so the worst complexity is `O(n*m)` where `m` is the number of possible tests.

Comment: But the possible number of tests is *constant*. The time complexity of that code is O(N). There might be a higher constant factor, but *algorithmically* they are equivalent.

Comment: Getting the dictionary value is `O(1)`, with the loop it's `O(m)` so there is a factor `m` speedup.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I added some timings to support this. (An ever better comparison would be to add more tests).

Comment: Those timings don't demonstrate what you are claiming at all, they merely demonstrate that the dictionary approach is *faster*, which is *not the same thing as algorithmically faster*. To try to support your claim empirically, you would need to *show how the algorithm scales*, and in one case, it would scale linearly, in the other, polynomially. But you will find that *both scale linearly because they are both O(N)*.

Comment: Fundamentally, the work done inside the loop in *both cases* is **constant time**. It is *not* O(M), there **is no M to vary**. So let me put this another way: in your analysis, what is M?

Comment: Well I think we have to disagree here (or maybe we're not talking about the same thing here). The dictionary approach is O(1*N) and the loop O(M*N). As mentioned in my comment, to really test scaling on M (the number of conditions) we would need to increase the number of conditions (which I said I haven't done). Of course on both cases the loop will be on the N elements.

Comment: **But that isn't how the analysis of algorithms works*. You can't *scale the number of branches*, that isn't an input to the algorithm! I'm sorry, but this is very fundamental. Both approaches are O(N).

Comment: The M/1 is what I called n/1 in the answer, the number of tests

Comment: *The number of tests is constant*, algorithmically, you can choose a constant number where *for any given input* the time taken to do that will be less than that constant number. The only variable input in *both cases* is the length of the input list, and *both* algorithms scale linearly *on that input*.

Comment: OK so we were not taking about the same thing. And my point is that the dictionary approach improves over the loop. The more tests you have the worse it is going to run while using a dictionary finds the correct value directly.

Comment: Then *you aren't talking about algorithmic complexity, e.g. O(N)*. I'm not trying to be difficult, but your statement about the algorithm being O(M\*N) is simply incorrect. Indeed, all the algorithms in your timings have the same time complexity. But of course, that doesn't mean that they are *all the same speed*. Again, this is pretty fundamental to the analysis of algorithms

Comment: I see no reason why the number of tests couldn't be a variable. If OP chooses to add more categories of elements more tests will be needed and the code will be slower. That said you're right for a fixed number of tests the algorithmic complexity of both approaches scales linearly relative to the number of items (I never claimed otherwise) ;)